# See the user data when connecting as an admin and press on specific user

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I have a system that works with JWT and for each call to the server side i pull the userid from token of JWT and fetch data according to the userid.

And what i need to do know is when an admin is enter to the system he will have list of users and when he press on user i need to show him the system(that is exists) in the eye of the same user.

The problem if i press on specific user and in the server side i use userid from token then i can't do what i need that is connect as admin and press on specific user and show the system as the user eye.

Let say for example i do log in as regular user and present in my system page of myProfucts(according to userid that user id is getting from token in server side) and now i want to do login as an admin user and i page that is only for admin called allusers and in that page i see all users in the system and when i press on user i want to go to the page myProducts and see the products of the user i pressed on.

Server side: web api. Client side: angular 11.

Comment: What version of Asp.Net are you using?

Comment: V: Net core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is user impersonation for which there isn't a default implementation as it depends on your situation.

This post however does go through a way to set it up which may help guide you in the right direction: https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/adding-user-impersonation-to-an-asp-net-core-web-application/